# How to implement ghost button in Android. Do NOT use multi layer.

Tags: android, android-button

I'd like to implement Ghost button for Android without using multi layer of item. So I just need to define the stroke and text. The button body will transparent to the background. Anyone get some good solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want multiple views for the button, then your only option is to define a background. Please take in mind that this approach will remove the cool ripple effect from the pressed state of the button. In the example below the color of the text and the border is black, but you can change it:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Text"/>
```

drawable/background_button_ghost.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

If I have missed something, please leave a comment and I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background to a GradientDrawable:

```
public static void setGhost(Button button) {
    Context context = button.getContext();
    int radius = RADIUS_IN_PIXELS;

    GradientDrawable background = new GradientDrawable();
    background.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    background.setStroke(STROKE_THICKNESS_IN_PIXELS, Color.WHITE);
    background.setCornerRadius(radius);
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}
```

I know it sounds a bit complicated to use a `GradientDrawable` for that but I believe this is what the system is doing when you define a `<shape>` resource